# Cannot run npm run serve

Tags: vue.js

I created a client project for vue and run npm run serve,
but got this error:

Tried to reinstall node,npm, edited some PATHS, but nothing worked

#### Version

3.2.1

#### Node and OS info

Node v10.14.0/ npm 6.4.1

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'serve' ]
    2 info using npm@6.4.1
    3 info using node@v10.14.0
    4 verbose run-script [ 'preserve', 'serve', 'postserve' ]
    5 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~preserve: client@0.1.0
    6 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~serve: client@0.1.0
    7 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~serve: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    8 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~serve: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/alexsexotic/Desktop/work/Test - mongod:node/client/node_modules/.bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Users/alexsexotic/.npm-global/bin
    9 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~serve: CWD: /Users/alexsexotic/Desktop/work/Test - mongod:node/client
    10 silly lifecycle client@0.1.0~serve: Args: [ '-c', 'vue-cli-service serve' ]
    11 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~serve: Failed to exec serve script
    12 verbose stack Error: client@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
    12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
    12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
    12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
    12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
    13 verbose pkgid client@0.1.0
    14 verbose cwd /Users/alexsexotic/Desktop/work/Test - mongod:node/client
    15 verbose Darwin 17.2.0
    16 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "serve"
    17 verbose node v10.14.0
    18 verbose npm  v6.4.1
    19 error file sh
    20 error code ELIFECYCLE
    21 error errno ENOENT
    22 error syscall spawn
    23 error client@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
    23 error spawn ENOENT
    24 error Failed at the client@0.1.0 serve script.
    24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Beautify your question a bit and put more details

Comment: show us your package.json, to see if in the "scripts" field you have the "serve"

Comment: @javimovi here you go

        {
          "name": "client",
          "version": "0.1.0",
          "private": true,
          "scripts": {
            "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
            "build": "vue-cli-service build",
            "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
          },

Comment: Can you run `npx serve` and see if it works?

Comment: @Aer0 WOW, it kinda work but my index.hmtl doesnt load,

Can i ask you how did you think about this solution ? I searched in many forums but noone solved it for me.

Comment: I assume you've been trying to use `vue-cli` to create that project. Did you install the cli globally or only within your project? That said. Did you bootstrap the whole project using `vue-cli` or by copying some stuff into your `package.json` and running `npm i` followed by `npm run serve`?

Comment: @Aer0 i installed vue-cli globally

Comment: @Aer0 npx serve worked, i executed it in the client folder, but it coudlnt open index.html with vue

Answer (score 0):

You may check your current cli installation and maybe reinstall your vue-cli. Basically, an `npx` command runs within your project directory. So running `npx [whatever]` will always use modules installed within your project itself while `npm run [whatever]` may refer to some globally installed dependencies.

That said, you might also try using yarn. In the past I've also had some trouble running vue-cli through `npm` so I switched to [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/).

However I can not help you regarding your `index.html` problem since this may be another issue. But if you've bootstrapped a fresh vue project throughout vue-cli, it should work.

Comment: So i need to install yarn in my folder and run yarn serve?

Comment: Install it globally. It is a lot faster than `npm` and has some more features too. Simply check out the website. It's actually the same as `npm` is - a node package manager.

Comment: now i got this error:

    has-macbook-air:client alexsexotic$ yarn run serve
    yarn run v1.12.3
    $ vue-cli-service serve
    /bin/sh: vue-cli-service: command not found
    error Command failed with exit code 127.
    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this    
    command.
    has-macbook-air:client alexsexotic$

Comment: Just seems like you don't have a globally installed version of the vue-cli. Did you try reinstalling it? Else I'd really have no idea anymore. I'm sorry.

Comment: After 2 days of struggle i decided to look at the error msg again, and realised that naming a folder with spacebar isnt a good idea, so i renamed it and it finally works

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

It's work for me.